# Debugging recursion in Prolog

Tags: debugging, recursion, prolog, trace

Here is my knowledge base:

```
numeral(0). 
numeral(succ(X))  :-  numeral(X).
```

Here is my query:

```
numeral(X).
```

Here is what  SWI Prolog returns in trace mode:

```
[trace]  ?- numeral(X).
   Call: (8) numeral(_3806) ? creep
   Exit: (8) numeral(0) ? creep
X = 0 ;
   Redo: (8) numeral(_3806) ? creep
   Call: (9) numeral(_4006) ? creep
   Exit: (9) numeral(0) ? creep
   Exit: (8) numeral(succ(0)) ? creep
X = succ(0) ;
   Redo: (9) numeral(_4006) ? creep
   Call: (10) numeral(_4010) ? creep
   Exit: (10) numeral(0) ? creep
   Exit: (9) numeral(succ(0)) ? creep
   Exit: (8) numeral(succ(succ(0))) ? creep
X = succ(succ(0))
```

I understand how it finds `X=0` answer, I do not fully grasp how it obtains: `X = succ(succ(0))`. I understand that this is correct answer, but I am not sure how Prologs searched for it.

Here is my thinking:
When it prints `Call: (9) numeral(_4006) ? creep` it tries this rule: `numeral(succ(X))  :-  numeral(X).` And in particular it probably substitutes `_4006 = succ(X)`
then it checks that it only holds when `numeral(X)` holds, which Prolog checks against `numeral(0)`, so result is `_4006 = succ(0)`.

Now if we ask for anther solution it again comes back to `numeral(_4006)`, but what does it guess when is calls `numeral(_4010)`. What is branching process here?

Is there way to get more details?

P.S. This is taken from the following [link](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog searches trough bactracking. There are two ways Prolog can aim to satisfy an `numeral(X)` call:

1. with `numeral(0)` in which case it unifies `X` with `0`; and
2. with `numeral(succ(Y)) :- numeral(Y)` in which case it unifies `X` with `succ(Y)` and makes a recursive call.

I here used `Y` since this also creates confusion: the variables in a clause are *locally scoped* in the sense that an `X` in a clause, is not the same variable as an `X` in a call.

Now in case Prolog backtracks and aims to satisfy the predicate with the clause, then this means that `X = succ(Y)` with `Y` a variable, but it needs to make an extra call with `numeral(Y)` as specified in the body.

Again there are two choices:

1. with `numeral(0)` in which case it unifies `Y` with `0`; and
2. with `numeral(succ(Z)) :- numeral(Z)` in which case it unifies `Y` with `succ(Z)` and makes a recursive call.

In case we go for the first one, `Y` is set to `0`, and thus `X = succ(Y)` hence `X = succ(0)`. In the latter case `X = succ(Y)`, and `Y = succ(Z)`, and we again make a recursive call.

Now in case we again use the first line for `numeral(0)`, this thus means that `Z` is unified with `0`, hence `Z = 0`, hence `Y = succ(0)`, hence `X = succ(succ(0))`.